# Unity still won't let me do a clean build despite installing the latest API

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, sdk, google-play-console

I keep receiving this error, despite installing API 32 using the Android SDK Manager.

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DYlQ.png)

I honestly don't know how else to fix this, I have tried restarting my PC as well.

Comment: Check your settings to make sure the SDK you've updated is the SDK Unity is using. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html